Strict top margin with align and \allowdisplaybreaks
In the following LaTeX document, which uses the align environment with \allowdisplaybreaks, the second equation extends into the top margin:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\setlength\maxdepth{0pt}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\vspace*{19cm}
\begin{align}
1+1=2\\
\frac{2}{\alpha}=\sum_{i} b_i
\end{align}
\end{document}

I know that \maxdepth needs to be set to 0pt for strict bottom margins. What can I do to make LaTeX strictly observe the top margin boundary? Could this be a bug in LaTeX / amsmath?

maxdepth=0 means you can't usually achieve a good baseline at the bottom of the page as descenders such as y will force the entire line up as they are not allowed to descend

You don't say exactly but presumably your concern is the 2 passing the line here

That is not really related to the math display, it is simply that the visual glyph is, by the choice of the font designer, taller than the bounding box of the character so TeX simply has no information about the top of the curve of the 2.
You can use \frac{\mathstrut 2}{\alpha to get

A simpler test
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

2\vrule width 3pt height \fontcharht\font `2 %
2\llap{\vrule width 3pt height \fontcharht\font `2 }%

\end{document}

Produces

Which shows the 2 being visibly taller than the height specified by the computer modern font metrics.
